# Ruby - update hash values with new values but only if different than original values

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I'm trying to find an efficient way to update an array of hashes with new values, but only updating the values that are different than the original values.

**Edit -** Added a CodeBunk of the below: http://codebunk.com/b/83947000/

For example:

```
h1        = { foo: "a", bar: "b" }
h2        = { foo: "a", bar: "c" }
h3        = { foo: "h", bar: "e" }
h4        = { foo: "s", bar: "b" }
h5        = { foo: "a"}
h6        = { foo: "y"}
h7        = { bar: "b"}
h8        = { bar: "z"}

hashes    = [h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8]

original  = { foo: "a", bar: "b" }
updated   = { foo: "x", bar: "f" }

hashes.each do |h|
  # magic?
end

# result: 
  # h1.insepct #=> { foo: "x", bar: "f" } 
  # Both "foo" and "bar" change because they both matched their original values; 

  # h2.insepct #=> { foo: "x", bar: "c" } 
  # Only "foo" changes; "bar" does NOT change because it has a value differnt than the original

  # h3.insepct #=> { foo: "h", bar: "e" } 
  # Neither "foo" nor "bar" change because neither value matched the original

  # h4.insepct #=> { foo: "s", bar: "f" } 
  # Only "bar" changes; "foo" does not change because it has a value different than the original

  # h5.inspect #=> { foo: "x" }
  # "foo" changes as it matched the original value; hash does not include "bar"

  # h6.inspect #=> { foo: "y" }
  # "foo" change; hash does not include "bar"

  # h7.inspect #=> { bar: "f" }
  # "bar" changes as it matched the original value; hash does not include "foo"

  # h8.inspect #=> { bar: "z" }
  # "bar" change; hash does not include "foo"
```

So far I've only been able to accomplish this with multiple nested loops. I'm really hoping there is a better way...

**Edit 2 - Here's my current solution which I would like to improve upon:**

```
  h1        = { foo: "a", bar: "b" }
  h2        = { foo: "a", bar: "c" }
  h3        = { foo: "h", bar: "e" }
  h4        = { foo: "s", bar: "b" }
  h5        = { foo: "a"}
  h6        = { foo: "y"}
  h7        = { bar: "b"}
  h8        = { bar: "z"}

  hashes    = [h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8]

  legend    = {}

  original_attrs  = { foo: "a", bar: "b" }
  updated_attrs   = { foo: "x", bar: "f" }

  updated_attrs.each do |k, v|
    legend[k] = { original_value: original_attrs[k], new_value: v }
  end

  hashes.each do |hsh|
    legend.each do |legend_key, legend_value|
      if hsh.has_key?(legend_key) && hsh[legend_key] == legend_value[:original_value]
        hsh[legend_key] = legend_value[:new_value]
      end
    end
  end

  logger.debug "hashes: #{hashes}"

  # hashes: [
  #   {:foo=>"x", :bar=>"f"},
  #   {:foo=>"x", :bar=>"c"},
  #   {:foo=>"h", :bar=>"e"},
  #   {:foo=>"s", :bar=>"f"},
  #   {:foo=>"x"},
  #   {:foo=>"y"},
  #   {:bar=>"f"},
  #   {:bar=>"z"}
  # ]
```

Comment: If you don't mind mutating the hashes, your code is fine, as it's economical and easy to read. A small point: some prefer writing `<statement> if <condition>` rather than `if <condition>; <statement>; end`.

Answer (score 1):

For purposes of illustration, I have used your example with the following changes:

```
h8             = { bar: "z", buz: "a"}
original_attrs = { foo: "a", bar: "b", booz: "pony" }
updated_attrs  = { foo: "x", bar: "f", booz: "pig" }
```

The first step is to construct a mapping from `original_attrs` to `updated_attrs`. In doing this I assume that both hashes share the same keys. We obtain:

```
attr_map = original_attrs.merge(updated_attrs) { |_,o,n| { o=>n } }
  #=> {:foo=>{"a"=>"x"}, :bar=>{"b"=>"f"}}
```

In fact, I think this would be a better data structure than parallel arrays for storing that information. The calculation uses the form of the method [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block (here `{ |_,o,n| { o=>n } }`) to compute the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Note this does not mutate `original_attrs` or `updated_attrs`.

If an element of `hashes` (a hash) has a key `:foo` with value `"a"`, we want to change that value to `attr_map[:foo]["a"] #=> "x"` in the corresponding hash in the array to which we are mapping `hashes`. If the value were something else, say `"r"`, we would want to leave it unchanged. One way of doing that is to use the method [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) to assign a default value for each value (hash) of `attr_map`:

```
attr_map.each { |_,h| h.default_proc = ->(_,v) { v } }
```

The result is that if `attr_map[:foo]` does not have a key `k`, `attr_map[:foo][k]` will return the value of the proc:

```
attr_map[:foo]['cat']
  #=> "cat"
```

which is the original value, meaning that `:foo=>'cat'` will remaining unchanged. The same is of course true for the other keys of `attr_map`. We can now perform the mapping as follows:

```
hashes.map { |g| g.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  h[k] = (attr_map.key?(k) ? attr_map[k][v] : v) } }
  #=> [{:foo=>"x", :bar=>"f"},
  #    {:foo=>"x", :bar=>"c"},
  #    {:foo=>"h", :bar=>"e"},
  #    {:foo=>"s", :bar=>"f"},
  #    {:foo=>"x"},
  #    {:foo=>"y"},
  #    {:bar=>"f"},
  #    {:bar=>"z", :buz=>"a"}]
```

This does not mutate `hashes`.

In summary, the code is:

```
attr_map = original_attrs.merge(updated_attrs) { |_,o,n| { o=>n } }
attr_map.each { |_,h| h.default_proc = ->(_,v) { v } }
hashes.map { |g| g.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  h[k] = (attr_map.key?(k) ? attr_map[k][v] : v) } }
```

Lastly, let me just say a few words about `each_with_object`'s block variables, which appear as

```
|(k,v),h|
```

`map` passes the first value of `hashes` (`h1`) into its block and it becomes the value of the block variable `g`:

```
g #=> { foo: "a", bar: "b" }
```

`each_with_object` then initializes the object to an empty hash, and then passes each element of `g`, together with the (updated) hash object, to its block. The first value it passes to the block is:

```
[[:foo, "a"], {}]
```

*Parallel assignment* and *disambiguation* are employed to assign values to the three block variables:

```
(k,v),h = [[:foo, "a"], {}]
  #=> [[:foo, "a"], {}] 
k #=> :foo 
v #=> "a" 
h #=> {}
```